# Graphics image size in BlueSky Statistics

Tags: graphics

In BlueSky Statistics, how can I change the default image size of the graphics displayed in the output? I have tried grabbing a corner and stretching it, and I've right-clicked on it to look for options.

Answer (score 0):

Image size can be changed in BlueSky Statistics in following two ways:
1) Go to 'Tools -> Configuration Settings' in the main window. A window will appear. Open 'Image' tab in this window. Specify new dimensions and click 'Save'.

2) In the 'Output Window' go to 'Image Size -> Change Graphic Size'.